# Load two ons-toolbar elements

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to load two ons-toolbar elements in the same template/controller and then switch between them depending on what my API is returning.

I have tried to use ng-show/ng-hide but Onsen seems to override this someway.

How to make this work?

Comment: Solved it by using ng-include